# Exception: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. (Parameter 'index')

Tags: c#, arrays, exception

I get this error:

Exception: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. (Parameter 'index')

```
string json = cli.DownloadString(url);
var getnumbers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(json);

int[] ToPick = { 44, 47, 57, 64, 55, 27, 11, 33 };
var picked = getnumbers.Intersect(ToPick);
Random rand = new Random();
var randomIndex = rand.Next(picked.Count());
var randompick = picked.ElementAt(randomIndex);
if (picked != null)
{
    /do something with the picked number
}
```

The getnumbers JSON is something like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Does anyone have any ideas what's wrong with it?

I only get the exception when a number from ToPick array is not found on the intersect and thus it doesn't exist in getnumbers array

Comment: Curious that you have `if (picked != null)` _after_ you've used `ElementAt` to retrieve an element from `picked`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ElementAt` does not return null. The `randomIndex` must be a valid index. Since none intersect. The array is empty and thus will throw an error. Add a condition to check if `picked.Count()` is greater than zero.

Edit: You can also use `ElementAtOrDefault` to return a null if the array is empty. Keep in mind that if your list contains null values. You should use a different value for the failure using `DefaultIfEmpty`.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. I'm accepting the answer.